# What does "think yourself" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

A BBC article is titled "Can you think yourself drunk?". What does it mean? There's no such an expression, "think yourself", as far as I know

Comment: This is a different usage, but [*think oneself*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/think%20oneself) is also an expression that means "Think *of* one's self as _____".  For example, "He thought himself very unlucky."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible and closely-related meanings:

- Think of yourself as being X (Think yourself lucky / fortunate / special / clever / young / wealthy / tall)
- Make yourself X by means of a thought process. (Think yourself calm / sober / decisive)

But of these, only "think yourself lucky" is really idiomatic, except as a question ("Think yourself poor? Just wait till next year...")

Comment: Normally that question would be phrased "Think you're poor?"

Answer (score 21):

It's an unusual expression, but it simply means **"make yourself drunk by thinking."**  It's similar to constructions like

> beat yourself black and blue (make yourself black and blue by beating)

or

> paint the wall red  (make the wall red by painting)

Comment: You sometimes hear of drunk people trying to 'think themselves sober' (become sober by the power of thought). I believe any perceived success is likely to be illusory, as it is with the common 'woo-medicine' idea, seen in various forms, which tries to sell sick people the idea that they can 'think themselves well'.

Comment: I'm not sure what the origin of this is, but there's a book called [Think Yourself Rich](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Think-Yourself-Rich-Subconscious-Wealth-ebook/dp/B01E7FWPS8) which supposedly tells you how to make yourself rich by thinking about it. And more recently Think Yourself Thin.

Comment: @StuartF - you can think yourself rich if your thinking leads you to write books about thinking yourself rich to sell to to gullible people, whose numbers, I am told, increase at the rate of one every minute.

Comment: I did once read about an experiment where subjects were given, a number of throwaway plastic beakers, containing either plain distilled water or the same with a healthy shot of vodka. A considerable number of the plain water drinkers reported feeling drunk and, indeed, became quite jolly in their demeanour.

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey That's the placebo effect, which is somewhat different from deliberately thinking yourself drunk.

Comment: @Barmar - yes, I knew that. Maybe I had thought myself a bit tipsy, and it had made me frivolous?